# jQuery Mobile Popups won't open after page refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page in a jQuery mobile app where there are several ajax forms submissions possible, and on 2 of those forms, upon the successful ajax response I reload the page like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
            transition : 'flip',
            reverse : false,
            changeHash: false,
            allowSamePageTransition : true,
            reloadPage:true
        });
```

After this refresh occurs the popups on the page will no longer open (until a hard refresh is done in the browser). I'm guessing it has something to do with jQM thinking there are 2 pages (even though its a reload of the same page), and since the same ID's exist its causing problems. How can I fix this?

Notes: my URLs have parameters in them and I have tried changing those so that the URLs wouldn't be exactly the same to see if it would help, but it doesn't. Also, if I navigate away from this page and go back to it later without the refresh from the AJAX calls, i have no issue.

Answer (score 0):

For every page You need to create seperate popups with different ID's then only its going to work..else it will show conflict.

Comment: I am talking about the same page here, not separate pages.